# Up-to-date getElementsByClassName Cross Browser - John Resig

Tags: javascript, class, dom, getelementsbyname

In 2007 John Resig posted an in depth article with speed tests:

http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/#postcomment

7 years later, what is currently the best way to get elements by class name?

Comment: document.querySelector() or document.querySelectorAll().

Comment: @Cypher No IE6 or IE7 for document.querySelector()

Comment: If you have to support browsers that are not even supported by their own developers, then you have more problems to worry about than selecting elements by class names. You asked for 7 years later, not 7 years ago.  ;-)

Comment: @meatgrinder you said "Cross Browser" not "Cross Dead-Browserlike-Programs"